# on select a option show higher value in other select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I use 2 select option for show budget price, 
when I select a price like 4000 then second select option show visible and display higher price than 4000. 
What jquery code should I use?
Here is my code:

DEMO
pls check

```
<li>
    <label>Budget</label>
    <select name="budget_from" id="budget_from" onchange="setBudgetFinal('1','1', 'requiremant_frm','3999999','19999','5999','1');" onblur="" onfocus="" class="budget" style="width: 89px; visibility: visible;">
        <option value="3999">&lt;4000</option>
        <option value="3000">3000</option>
        <option value="5000">5000</option>
        <option value="7000">7000</option>
        <option value="9000">9000</option>
        <option value="11000">11000</option>
        <option value="13000">13000</option>
        <option value="15000">15000</option>
        <option value="17000">17000</option>
        <option value="19000">19000</option>
        <option value="21000">21000</option>
        <option value="25000">25000</option>
        <option value="30000">30000</option>
        <option value="40000">40000</option>
        <option value="45000">45000</option>
        <option value="50000">50000</option>
        <option value="55000">55000</option>
        <option value="60000">60000</option>
        <option value="65000">65000</option>
        <option value="70000">70000</option>
        <option value="75000">75000</option>
        <option value="80000">80000</option>
        <option value="85000">85000</option>
        <option value="90000">90000</option>
        <option value="95000">95000</option>
        <option value="100000">1 Lac</option>
        <option value="105000">1.05 Lacs</option>
        <option value="110000">1.10 Lacs</option>
        <option value="115000">&gt;1.15 Lacs</option>
    </select>
    <span id="sc"> to</span>
    <select style="visibility: visible;" disabled="" id="budget_to" name="budget_to" class="budget">
        <option value="">Max Price</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Comment: Select elements are not dependent of each other without a JS code. Please show the code you have, and if possible, try to reword your question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#budget_from option').on('click', function(){
        $('#budget_to').find('option').not(':first').remove();
    $(this).nextAll().clone(true).appendTo('#budget_to');
    $('#budget_to').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLMKV/)</kbd>

Comment: but this not work on my page
i also upload jquery 1.7.2 on my but it does not work 
how?...